# Give dynamic ID to a div which comes from other parent component

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-input

I have a chart component like below:

```
<div id="chart">
    <ngx-charts-bar-horizontal [view]="view" [trimYAxisTicks]="false" [xAxisTickFormatting]="convertDecimalToNumber" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="data" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showDataLabel]="showDataLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [barPadding]="40">
    </ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
</div>
```

I am manipulating all the styles of this chart by it's parent div here which has `id="chart"`, but I need above same component 2 times in a parent component! So that creates problem with same 2 ids.

So, I decided to pass div's id from parent component as an `@Input()` like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Other tags -->
    <child-component [chartId]="users"></child-component>
    <!-- Other tags -->
    <child-component [chartId]="visuals"></child-component>
    <!-- Other tags -->
</div>
```

Edit on child component:

TS File:

```
@Input() chartId: string;
```

HTML:

```
<div [id]="chartId">
    <ngx-charts-bar-horizontal [view]="view" [trimYAxisTicks]="false" [xAxisTickFormatting]="convertDecimalToNumber" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="data" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showDataLabel]="showDataLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [barPadding]="40">
    </ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
</div>
```

> I tried these techniques: [id]="chartId", [attr.id]="chartId", id="{{chartId}}"

but none of above worked to set the dynamic id from Input.

Comment: Hi @Hope can you tell me what values you are getting in ` chartId` of `<div [id]="chartId">`?

Comment: @Coderman undefined

Comment: okay, I posted the answer you can try and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: @Hope Do you want to set Id property dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="chart"> </div>
```

component:

```
@Input() chartId: string;
ngOnChanges(): void {
    const parent_div = document.getElementById('chart');
    parent_div.setAttribute('id', this.chartId);
}
```

In your child component give some initial id as a default value and use ngOnChanges to update the id.

Comment: Best in Answer. You just removed my headache.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

In parent component.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Other tags -->
    <child-component chartId="users"></child-component>
    <!-- Other tags -->
    <child-component chartId="visuals"></child-component>
    <!-- Other tags -->
</div>
```

and in your child component.ts:

```
@Input() chartId: string;
```

and in your child component.html file:

```
<div id="{{ chartId }}">
    <ngx-charts-bar-horizontal [view]="view" [trimYAxisTicks]="false" [xAxisTickFormatting]="convertDecimalToNumber" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="data" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showDataLabel]="showDataLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [barPadding]="40">
    </ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

If the above solution didn't work for you try this:

in the parent component.ts file declare two variables:

```
users: string = 'yourID1';
visuals: string = 'yourID2';
```

and in parent component.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Other tags -->
    <child-component [chartId]="users"></child-component>
    <!-- Other tags -->
    <child-component [chartId]="visuals"></child-component>
    <!-- Other tags -->
</div>
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Okay No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is at your ViewEncapsulation level. 
Even more, if you're trying to style a dom element inside your `<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal/>` .

I think you may use the *ViewEncapsulation.None* option inside your *ChildComponent*.

Comment: Okay i will try that, but can you tell me which method will work from the methods I have tried for ID?

Comment: **id="{{chartId}}"** .